# jQuery callback not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is a portion of my script, it prints 9 then 98 but fails to print 2 it indicates that the callback function in jQuery is not called. However before this I am printing the json returned from the php file using json_decode function and json is printed absolutely fine. How can I go about debugging it, I mean where could be the error?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
alert(9);
$('#charac').keyup( function() {
alert(98);
  $.getJSON('myprg.php?q='+escape($('#charac').val()), function(data) {
    alert(2);
```

Comment: Do you know that the server is returning a successful response? Confirm that first.

Comment: You can debug it with firebug. Have a look at http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging for tutorial if you never debug with firebug before

Comment: @BZink: Server is returning an absolutely fine valid JSON (which I even validated)

Comment: are you serving the file using the JSON mime type?

Comment: @gillesc: header( 'Content-type: application/json;' );

Comment: Then we'll probably need to see more of your script to see what the issue could be. How are you printing the JSON if your callback isn't being called?

Comment: @Bzink: In my php file which is being called from the html file where my jQuery resides I just give print json_encode($php_array)

Comment: Are you closing your braces?  I assume so, but your example code is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$.ajax` function instead of `getJSON` and use the error callback to see what's going on.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
  error: callback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

It can also be useful to inspect the actual server response with Firebug or Chrome developer tools and validate the JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), some JSON libraries are more forgiving than others and ignore small errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the method described by you and finally it printed me status to be 200 which I printed using alert(jgXHR.status) & than I printed alert(errorThrown) which gave me the following message: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: Finally solved the problem. Thanks a ton for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer, but the code is visualized better here.

Does the following also fail (using jQuery 1.5 or later)?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    alert(9);
    $('#charac').keyup( function() {
        alert(98);
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON('myprg.php?q='+escape($('#charac').val()), function(data) {
            alert(2);
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
    });
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    alert(9);
    $('#charac').keyup( function() {
        alert(98);
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON('myprg.php?q='+escape($('#charac').val()), function(data) {
            alert(2);
        });

        jqxhr.success(function() { alert("second success"); });
        jqxhr.error(function() { alert("error"); });
        jqxhr.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mario for helping. Firebug prints this: $.getJSON("myprg.php?q=" + escape($("#charac").val()), function (data) {alert(2);}).error is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

.error(function() { alert("error"); })

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Does the second example work? I mean, do you get any alert?

Comment: <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">. This time the firebug says:jqxhr.success is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

jqxhr.success(function() { alert("second success"); })

Comment: No I dont get any alert after 98

Comment: Oh, ok, well, it's because you need jQuery 1.5 or later to make that code work. *Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.*

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to jQuery 1.5 or later? Otherwise, I would try mariom's answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Mario. It now prints the alert "Error" and then "complete", it does not go into printing 2 and second success. So should I go in debugging JSON because I am seeing json string in firebug and also I tested for it being well formed and it was fine. I am confused as to why the function might fail? Thanks for your help +1